# The input String is not in correct format even though my variable is an integer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Private Sub shirtnum_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles shirtnum.KeyPress ("this is suppose to type in any number using into the textbox using your keyboard")
    Dim Ch As Char = e.KeyChar
    If Not Char.IsDigit(Ch) AndAlso Asc(Ch) <> 8 Then
        e.Handled = True

    End If
End Sub 

Private Sub addshbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addshbtn.Click
    Dim t As Integer = Integer.Parse(shirtnum.Text) ("this is to add 1 number to the textbox")
    t += 1
    shirtnum.Text = t
    addshbtn.Enabled = True
    pricetxt_TextChanged(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub minusshbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles minusshbtn.Click ("this is to minus 1 number from the textbox")
    Dim t As Integer = Integer.Parse(shirtnum.Text)
    t += -1
    If t <= 0 Then
        t = 0
    End If
    shirtnum.Text = t
    pricetxt_TextChanged(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub shirtnum_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles shirtnum.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub pricetxt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pricetxt.TextChanged
    "Dim t As Integer = Integer.Parse(shirtnum.Text) -- this is where the error appears **NOTE** this this code works without this sub"
    t = 1.0
    pricetxt.Text = ("$" & t * 15 & ".00")
    pricetxt.BorderStyle = 0
    pricetxt.BackColor = Me.BackColor

End Sub
```

Got an issue with my assignment is that the code appears to say that the input string is not in the correct format, even though my integer is a number.

If someone can help me out with this, this would be a big help, thanks!

Comment: Using the TextChanged event to format the number is not appropriate, use the Leave event instead.  Right now it bombs because assigning the Text property triggers TextChanged again, causing Integer.Parse() to fail.

Comment: I don't think you should even be using the Leave event. You should probably be handling both Validating and Validated. Confirm that the input is valid in the former and format the input in the latter. You would use TryParse to validate and then Parse to convert. You should also use ToString("C2") to format. If the app may be used under different cultures, specify a culture that uses dollars.

Comment: You really ought to get rid of all those controls. Add a `NumericUpDown` for the number of shirts, which has its own inbuilt increment and decrement buttons. You also won't have to worry about validating text input. You can handle the `ValueChanged` event, get the `Value` property, multiply it by the price of a single shirt and then display the result in a `Label` as currency using `myLabel.Text = totalPrice.ToString("C2")`.

Comment: If you really must use a `TextBox` and `Buttons` for this homework, DO NOT call the `TextChanged` event handler directly. NEVER call an event handler directly. Just write a method that gets the number of shirts from the `TextBox`, multiplies it by the price per shirt and then displays the result as I described above, whether in a `TextBox` (which should be read-only, so the user can't type into it) or a `Label`.

Comment: Also, why are you enabling a `Button` in its own `Click` event handler? How was it clicked if it's not enabled? The only `Button` you should be disabling is the decrement `Button`, when the count is zero. No point allowing them to try to decrement when they can't. You would then enable it in the `Click` event handler of the increment `Button` because you know that they can always decrement if they just incremented.